# Check for null in map function in Kotlin

Tags: nullpointerexception, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I want to map an object (ProductVisibility) base on another one (fmpProduct). Some object can't be converted so I need to skip them on some condition.

I wanted to know if there's a better way to do this than what I did with the filter and the "!!" I feel that it's hacked. Am I missing something ?

```
val newCSProductVisibility = fmpProducts
            .filter { parentIdGroupedByCode.containsKey(it.id) }
            .filter { ProductType.fromCode(it.type) != null } //voir si on accumule les erreus dans une variable à montrer
            .map {
                val type = ProductType.fromCode(it.type)!! //Null already filtered
                val userGroupIds = type.productAvailabilityUserGroup.map { it.id }.joinToString(",")
                val b2bGroupIds = type.b2bUserGroup.map { it.id }.joinToString { "," }
                val b2bDescHide = !type.b2bUserGroup.isEmpty() 
                val parentId = parentIdGroupedByCode[it.id]!! //Null already filtered

                CSProductDao.ProductVisibility(parentId, userGroupIds, b2bGroupIds, b2bDescHide)
            }
```

edit: updated the map access like comment suggested

Comment: To read the map value, you should probably use the array annotation instead: parentIdGroupedByCode[it.id]

Comment: I updated the map to access it like you said thanks, but it's still nullable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `mapNotNull()` to avoid the `filter()`s and do everything in the `mapNotNull()` block, then the automatic typecast to `non-null` type works. 
Example:

```
fun f() {

   val list = listOf<MyClass>()

   val v = list.mapNotNull {
       if (it.type == null) return@mapNotNull null
       val type = productTypeFromCode(it.type)
       if (type == null) return@mapNotNull null
       else MyClass2(type) // type is automatically casted to type!! here
   }


}

fun productTypeFromCode(code: String): String? {
    return null
}


class MyClass(val type: String?, val id: String)

class MyClass2(val type: String)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of mapNotNull. But what is return@mapNotNull null. When I tried your code it worked, but when I tried with mine I had to add it to my returned object because there was a cast error that I don't know where it came.  return@mapNotNull CSProductDao.ProductVisibility(parentId, userGroupIds, b2bGroupIds, b2bDescHide) I couldn't find the doc on @mapNotNull, my googling is getting poor :(

Comment: I found my answer. It's a return label, it makes sense : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels